# Sqlite and Python -- return a dictionary using fetchone()?

Tags: python, database, sqlite, dictionary

I'm using sqlite3 in python 2.5.  I've created a table that looks like this:

```
   create table votes (
      bill text,
      senator_id text,
      vote text)
```

I'm accessing it with something like this:

```
v_cur.execute("select * from votes")
row = v_cur.fetchone()
bill = row[0]
senator_id = row[1]
vote = row[2]
```

What I'd like to be able to do is have fetchone (or some other method) return a dictionary, rather than a list, so that I can refer to the field by name rather than position.  For example:

```
bill = row['bill'] 
senator_id = row['senator_id']
vote = row['vote']
```

I know you can do this with MySQL, but does anyone know how to do it with SQLite?

Thanks!!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get dict from sqlite query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3300464/how-can-i-get-dict-from-sqlite-query)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to retrieve SQL result column value using column name in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10195139/how-to-retrieve-sql-result-column-value-using-column-name-in-python)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The way I've done this in the past:

```
def dict_factory(cursor, row):
    d = {}
    for idx,col in enumerate(cursor.description):
        d[col[0]] = row[idx]
    return d
```

Then you set it up in your connection:

```
from pysqlite2 import dbapi2 as sqlite
conn = sqlite.connect(...)
conn.row_factory = dict_factory
```

This works under pysqlite-2.4.1 and python 2.5.4.

Comment: Not even quick and dirty, the row_factory hook would be the sanest way to do this per-connection. Mind you, at least the builtin sqlite3 module already comes with a suitable row factory: sqlite3.Row [ http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html#row-objects ]

Comment: Thank you! The method dict_factory() works on psycopg2 (postgres), too.

Answer (score 77):

There is actually an option for this in sqlite3.  Change the `row_factory` member of the connection object to `sqlite3.Row`:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('db', row_factory=sqlite3.Row)
```

or

```
conn.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
```

This will allow you to access row elements by name--dictionary-style--or by index.  This is much more efficient than creating your own work-around.

Comment: This is actually advised explicitly in `sqlite3` module docs: http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html#row-objects "

Comment: Be careful however when using sqlite3.Row, you can't use the row[1:3] syntax anymore, nor can you use a row generator as input for an INSERT statement. The sqlite3.Row is actually a butchered implementation.

Comment: According to docs it should be conn = sqlite3.connect('db', factory=sqlite3.Row)?

Comment: @andig: Could you give a link to the doc to which you're referring?  The ones I've looked at indicate that member of the `conn` object we're assigning is `row_factory`.  It could have changed, I suppose; it's been almost three years since I gave this answer.

Comment: @Eric: Newbie's mistake- referring to http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html I was looking at the connection's, not the row's factory :(

Comment: Note that this does not return an actual dictionary, as the question requested.

Answer (score 11):

I was recently trying to do something similar while using sqlite3.Row(). While sqlite3.Row() is great for providing a dictionary-like interface or a tuple like interface, it didn't work when I piped in the row using **kwargs. So, needed a quick way of converting it to a dictionary. I realised that the Row() object can be converted to a dictionary simply by using itertools.

Python 2:

```
db.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
dbCursor = db.cursor()
dbCursor.execute("SELECT * FROM table")
row = dbCursor.fetchone()

rowDict = dict(itertools.izip(row.keys(), row))
```

Or in Python 3, more simply:

```
dbCursor = db.cursor()
dbCursor.execute("SELECT * FROM table")
row = dbCursor.fetchone()
rowDict = dict(zip([c[0] for c in dbCursor.description], row))
```

Similarly, you can use the dbCursor.fetchall() command and convert the entire set of rows to a list of dictionaries in a for loop.

Comment: A simpler form (for Python 3): dict(row)

Comment: dict(row) depends on the row factory returning something that can be converted to a dict, which is not a requirement of DBAPI2, so the examples here are more portable.

Answer (score 5):

Sure, make yourself a DictConnection and DictCursor as explained and shown at http://trac.edgewall.org/pysqlite.org-mirror/wiki/PysqliteFactories for example.

Comment: wouldn't this be preferred over the accepted solution, which looks dirty?

Comment: @Cawas, I agree, but the original asker doesn't seem to be around so there's no way to change what _he_ chose to accept a year ago!-)

Comment: yeah, I know that's how SO works... I just wanted to confirm if it really would be preferred. ;-)

Comment: @Cawas: you can use your vote to bubble this answer up, and sink the dirty solution

Comment: The problem is the link does not work any longer

Answer (score 2):

I know you're not asking this, but why not just use sqlalchemy to build an orm for the database?  then you can do things like,

```
entry = model.Session.query(model.Votes).first()
print entry.bill, entry.senator_id, entry.vote
```

as an added bonus your code will be easily portable to an alternative database, and connections and whatnot will be managed for free.

Answer (score 1):

I've used this:

```
def get_dict(sql):
    return dict(c.execute(sql,()).fetchall())
```

Then you can do this:

```
c = conn.cursor()
d = get_dict("select user,city from vals where user like 'a%'");
```

Now `d` is a dictionary where the keys are `user` and the values are `city`. This also works for `group by`

Comment: are you missing a double quote at the end of `d`?

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution, initialize a cursor object:

```
cursor = conn.cursor(buffered = True, dictionary = True)
```

Another option:

```
cursor = conn.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
```

Rest of Code:

```
query = "SELECT * FROM table"
cursor.execute(query)
row = cursor.fetchone()
```

Sources:  [mysql.connector.cursor](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor.html) , [MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb-1.2.2/public/MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor-class.html)

Answer (score 0):

I use something like this:

```
class SqliteRow(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.fields = []

    def add_field(self, name, value):
        self.fields.append(name)
        setattr(self, name, value)

    def to_tuple(self):
        return tuple([getattr(self, x) for x in self.fields])
```

with this:

```
def myobject_factory(cursor, row):
    myobject= MyObject()
    for idx, col in enumerate(cursor.description):
        name, value = (col[0], row[idx])

        myobject.add_field(name, value)
    return myobject
```

`MyObject()` is a class that inherits from `SqliteRow`.
SqliteRow class is a base class for every object that I want to have returned by a query.
Every column becomes an attribute and is logged into the `fields` list.
Function `to_tuple` is used to change the whole object to a form suitable for queries (simply pass the whole object and forget).

To get different class types of that function. You would need to make a factory object, that will generate objects based on the list of fields (for example: dict with { some_unique_value_made_of_fields: class}  )

This way I get a simple ORM.