# How can I get dict from sqlite query?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, dictionary, dataformat

```
db = sqlite.connect("test.sqlite")
res = db.execute("select * from table")
```

With iteration I get lists coresponding to the rows.

```
for row in res:
    print row
```

I can get name of the columns

```
col_name_list = [tuple[0] for tuple in res.description]
```

But is there some function or setting to get dictionaries instead of list?

```
{'col1': 'value', 'col2': 'value'}
```

or I have to do myself?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python - mysqlDB, sqlite result as dictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4147707/python-mysqldb-sqlite-result-as-dictionary)

Answer (score 289, accepted):

You could use [row_factory](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.row_factory), as in the example in the docs:

```py
import sqlite3

def dict_factory(cursor, row):
    d = {}
    for idx, col in enumerate(cursor.description):
        d[col[0]] = row[idx]
    return d

con = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
con.row_factory = dict_factory
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("select 1 as a")
print cur.fetchone()["a"]
```

or follow the advice that's given right after this example in the docs:

> If returning a tuple doesn’t suffice
> and you want name-based access to
> columns, you should consider setting
> row_factory to the highly-optimized
> sqlite3.Row type. Row provides both
> index-based and case-insensitive
> name-based access to columns with
> almost no memory overhead. It will
> probably be better than your own
> custom dictionary-based approach or
> even a db_row based solution.

Here is the code for this second solution:

```py
con = sqlite3.connect(…)
con.row_factory = sqlite3.Row   #   add this row
cursor = con.cursor()
```

Comment: If your column names have special characters in them eg `SELECT 1 AS "dog[cat]"` then the `cursor` will not have the correct description to create a dict.

Comment: I've set `connection.row_factory = sqlite3.Row` and I tried `connection.row_factory = dict_factory` as shown but `cur.fetchall()` is still giving me a list of tuples - any idea why this is not working?

Comment: @displayname, isn't documentation states "It tries to mimic a tuple in most of its features.". I'm pretty sure it is somehow similar to what you can get from `collections.namedtuple`. When I use `cur.fetchmany()` I get entries like `<sqlite3.Row object at 0x...>`.

Answer (score 73):

I thought I answer this question even though the answer is partly mentioned in both Adam Schmideg's  and Alex Martelli's answers. In order for others like me that have the same question, to find the answer easily.

```
conn = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")

#This is the important part, here we are setting row_factory property of
#connection object to sqlite3.Row(sqlite3.Row is an implementation of
#row_factory)
conn.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('select * from stocks')

result = c.fetchall()
#returns a list of dictionaries, each item in list(each dictionary)
#represents a row of the table
```

Comment: Currently `fetchall()` seems to return `sqlite3.Row` objects. However these can be converted to a dictionary simply by using `dict()`: `result = [dict(row) for row in c.fetchall()]`.

Comment: Unfortunately, the `sqlite3.Row` is not duck-type compatible with `dict` because `row.get('col')` fails.  sigh... i have to write my own and monkey patch the Row class.

Comment: yes the object returned by sqlite3.Row factory is different, available methods of both types can be checked using dir(row). Using sqlite3.Row a row element call row.keys () returns ['col'] (or the list of columns) and row['col'] the value of that column which might be enough for many purposes.

Answer (score 24):

Even using the sqlite3.Row class-- you still can't use string formatting in the form of:

```
print "%(id)i - %(name)s: %(value)s" % row
```

In order to get past this, I use a helper function that takes the row and converts to a dictionary. I only use this when the dictionary object is preferable to the Row object (e.g. for things like string formatting where the Row object doesn't natively support the dictionary API as well). But use the Row object all other times.

```
def dict_from_row(row):
    return dict(zip(row.keys(), row))
```

Comment: sqlite3.Row implements the mapping protocol.  You can just do `print "%(id)i - %(name)s: %(value)s" % dict(row)`

Answer (score 24):

After you connect to SQLite:
`con = sqlite3.connect(.....)` it is sufficient to just run:

```
con.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
```

Voila!

Answer (score 11):

As mentioned by @gandalf's answer, one has to use `conn.row_factory = sqlite3.Row`, but the results are *not directly* dictionaries. One has to add an additional "cast" to `dict` in the last loop:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
conn.execute('create table t (a text, b text, c text)')
conn.execute('insert into t values ("aaa", "bbb", "ccc")')
conn.execute('insert into t values ("AAA", "BBB", "CCC")')
conn.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('select * from t')
for r in c.fetchall():
    print(dict(r))

# {'a': 'aaa', 'b': 'bbb', 'c': 'ccc'}
# {'a': 'AAA', 'b': 'BBB', 'c': 'CCC'}
```

Answer (score 8):

From [PEP 249](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/):

```
Question: 

   How can I construct a dictionary out of the tuples returned by
   .fetch*():

Answer:

   There are several existing tools available which provide
   helpers for this task. Most of them use the approach of using
   the column names defined in the cursor attribute .description
   as basis for the keys in the row dictionary.

   Note that the reason for not extending the DB API specification
   to also support dictionary return values for the .fetch*()
   methods is that this approach has several drawbacks:

   * Some databases don't support case-sensitive column names or
     auto-convert them to all lowercase or all uppercase
     characters.

   * Columns in the result set which are generated by the query
     (e.g.  using SQL functions) don't map to table column names
     and databases usually generate names for these columns in a
     very database specific way.

   As a result, accessing the columns through dictionary keys
   varies between databases and makes writing portable code
   impossible.
```

So yes, do it yourself.

Comment: > varies between databases - like what, sqlite 3.7 and 3.8?

Comment: @user1123466: ... Like between SQLite, MySQL, Postgres, Oracle, MS SQL Server, Firebird...

Answer (score 6):

Shorter version:

```
db.row_factory = lambda c, r: dict([(col[0], r[idx]) for idx, col in enumerate(c.description)])
```

Answer (score 6):

Fastest on my tests:

```
conn.row_factory = lambda c, r: dict(zip([col[0] for col in c.description], r))
c = conn.cursor()

%timeit c.execute('SELECT * FROM table').fetchall()
19.8 µs ± 1.05 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

vs:

```
conn.row_factory = lambda c, r: dict([(col[0], r[idx]) for idx, col in enumerate(c.description)])
c = conn.cursor()

%timeit c.execute('SELECT * FROM table').fetchall()
19.4 µs ± 75.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

You decide :)

Answer (score 5):

Similar like before-mentioned solutions, but most compact:

```
db.row_factory = lambda C, R: { c[0]: R[i] for i, c in enumerate(C.description) }
```

Answer (score 2):

**Get the results of the query**

```
output_obj = con.execute(query)
results = output_obj.fetchall()
```

**Option 1) Explicit Loop w/ Zip**

```
for row in results:
    col_names = [tup[0] for tup in output_obj.description]
    row_values = [i for i in row]
    row_as_dict = dict(zip(col_names,row_values))
```

**Option 2) Faster Loop w/ Dict Comp**

```
for row in results:
    row_as_dict = {output_obj.description[i][0]:row[i] for i in range(len(row))}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you were on the right track. Let's keep this very simple and complete what you were trying to do:

```py
import sqlite3
db = sqlite3.connect("test.sqlite3")
cur = db.cursor()
res = cur.execute("select * from table").fetchall()
data = dict(zip([c[0] for c in cur.description], res[0]))

print(data)
```

**The downside is that `.fetchall()`, which is murder on your memory consumption**, if your table is very large. But for trivial applications dealing with mere few thousands of rows of text and numeric columns, this simple approach is good enough.

For serious stuff, you should look into row factories, as proposed in many other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could convert the sqlite3.Rows to a dictionary as follows. This will give a dictionary with a list for each row.

```
    def from_sqlite_Row_to_dict(list_with_rows):
    ''' Turn a list with sqlite3.Row objects into a dictionary'''
    d ={} # the dictionary to be filled with the row data and to be returned

    for i, row in enumerate(list_with_rows): # iterate throw the sqlite3.Row objects            
        l = [] # for each Row use a separate list
        for col in range(0, len(row)): # copy over the row date (ie. column data) to a list
            l.append(row[col])
        d[i] = l # add the list to the dictionary   
    return d
```

Answer (score 0):

A generic alternative, using just three lines

```
def select_column_and_value(db, sql, parameters=()):
    execute = db.execute(sql, parameters)
    fetch = execute.fetchone()
    return {k[0]: v for k, v in list(zip(execute.description, fetch))}

con = sqlite3.connect('/mydatabase.db')
c = con.cursor()
print(select_column_and_value(c, 'SELECT * FROM things WHERE id=?', (id,)))
```

But if your query returns nothing, will result in error. In this case...

```
def select_column_and_value(self, sql, parameters=()):
    execute = self.execute(sql, parameters)
    fetch = execute.fetchone()

    if fetch is None:
        return {k[0]: None for k in execute.description}

    return {k[0]: v for k, v in list(zip(execute.description, fetch))}
```

or

```
def select_column_and_value(self, sql, parameters=()):
    execute = self.execute(sql, parameters)
    fetch = execute.fetchone()

    if fetch is None:
        return {}

    return {k[0]: v for k, v in list(zip(execute.description, fetch))}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import sqlite3

db = sqlite3.connect('mydatabase.db')
cursor = db.execute('SELECT * FROM students ORDER BY CREATE_AT')
studentList = cursor.fetchall()

columnNames = list(map(lambda x: x[0], cursor.description)) #students table column names list
studentsAssoc = {} #Assoc format is dictionary similarly


#THIS IS ASSOC PROCESS
for lineNumber, student in enumerate(studentList):
    studentsAssoc[lineNumber] = {}

    for columnNumber, value in enumerate(student):
        studentsAssoc[lineNumber][columnNames[columnNumber]] = value


print(studentsAssoc)
```

The result is definitely true, but I do not know the best.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries in python provide arbitrary access to their elements.
So any dictionary with "names" although it might be informative on one hand (a.k.a. what are the field names) "un-orders" the fields, which might be unwanted.

Best approach is to get the names in a separate list and then combine them with the results by yourself, if needed.

```
try:
         mycursor = self.memconn.cursor()
         mycursor.execute('''SELECT * FROM maintbl;''')
         #first get the names, because they will be lost after retrieval of rows
         names = list(map(lambda x: x[0], mycursor.description))
         manyrows = mycursor.fetchall()

         return manyrows, names
```

Also remember that the names, in all approaches, are the names you provided in the query, not the names in database. Exception is the `SELECT * FROM`

If your only concern is to get the results using a dictionary, then definitely use the `conn.row_factory = sqlite3.Row` (already stated in another answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
def getUsers(self,assoc=False):
        result = self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM users").fetchall()
        result_len = len(result)
        if(result_len == False): return
        if(assoc != True):
            return result
        else:
            result_formated = []
            columns = [column[0] for column in self.cursor.description]
            for row in result:
                row_dict = {}
                i = 0
                # print(result_len)
                while(i <= result_len):
                    row_dict[columns[i]] = row[i]
                    i += 1
                result_formated.append(row_dict)
            return result_formated
```

i'll just leave my bad code here

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).