# Best practice for referencing SQL results to build Python lists?

Tags: python, mysql, list, mapping

Let's say I pull 20 columns of data from a database table of 100 rows:

```
result = cursor.fetchall()
```

Now I want to build a new table (2 dimensional list) based in part on this data (some columns will be mapped, some transformed). An error-prone method would be to refer to the applicable index from the result list:

```
newTable = []
for row in result:
  newTable.append(row[5], row[4], 0, some_function(row[1]), ...)
```

What's the best way to track the columns of `result` so we're not just referring to position numbers in the `append` statement, which would all have to be updated if we change the number of columns extracted in the database query?

Comment: You probably want to [get the row results as a dictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4147707/python-mysqldb-sqlite-result-as-dictionary).

Comment: Thank you for finding this similar question

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to create a row factory

```
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
con.row_factory = sqlite3.Row


cursor = con.execute("SELECT * FROM SOME_TABLE")
for row in cursor:
    print row["field_name"]
```

at least I think