# How to return JSON from Python REST API

Tags: python, mysql, json, rest, python-3.x

I have a Python API that receives data from mysql select query. The data looks like this:

```
| val | type | status |
|-----|------|--------|
|  90 |    1 |      a |
```

That data was received well in python. Now I want to present that data as JSON to my REST client - how?

Here is my python code:

```
def somefunction(self, by, identifier):
    # validate args
    procedure = 'mysproc' + str(by)

    try:
        with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.callproc(procedure,[str(identifier)])
            self.connection.commit()
            result = cursor.fetchone()

            print("+++ Result: " + str(result) + " +++")
    except:
        result = "Request Failed"
        raise
    finally:
        self.DestroyConnection()

    return json.dumps(result)
```

with that, my client is receiving:

```
"[90, 1, "a"]"
```

Question:

is there a way for me to receive it as a proper JSON? like:

```
{'val': 90, 'type': 1 , : 'status': "a"}
```

Comment: you have to parse json string yourself on client side, e.g do json.loads if it's a python client.

Comment: Do the inverse of `json.dumps(my_obj)`, by calling `json.loads(my_string)`

Comment: `>>> x=[90, 1, "a"]
>>> d={'val':x[0],'type':x[1],'status':x[2]}
>>> json.dumps(d)
'{"status": "a", "type": 1, "val": 90}'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will first need to get the mysql query to return a dict object instead of a list. If your library is MySQLdb then this answer: [Python - mysqlDB, sqlite result as dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4147707/python-mysqldb-sqlite-result-as-dictionary) is what you need.

Here is a link to the docs for MySQLdb: http://www.mikusa.com/python-mysql-docs/docs/MySQLdb.connections.html

I think if you pass in the cursor class you want to use when you create your cursor the result of fetchone will be a dictionary.

```
with self.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor) as cursor:
```

Running json.dumps(result) on a dictionary will give the output you are looking for.