# I can't figure out how to perform the SUM function on a DB and store the value into a python variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I'm trying to make an expense tracker with Python and SQLite3. I've figured out how to input data and the fields are as follows:
Amount Category(Food, Leisure, Transport, Education) Description DateOfPurchase
I'm trying to create a method so I can get the sum of all the expenses of a certain category in the month and put it into a python variable (because I want to further process and create a pie chart of the different categories)

I've tried working with the SELECT SQL function but I'm not sure how to go about solving the problem

```
import sqlite3
import datetime
import time

connectdb = sqlite3.connect("Expenses.db")
c = connectdb.cursor()


def create_table():
    c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Expenses (Amount REAL, Category 
TEXT, Description TEXT, DateOfPurchase TEXT)")


# used to input a record
def datain():
    amount = float(input("Please enter the amount of money paid for the 
             expense"))
    Today = str(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time()).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
    category = str(input("Please pick a category from Food, Transport, 
               Leisure, Education"))
    temp = ("Food", "Transport", "Leisure", "Education")
    while not (category in temp):
        category = str(input("Please pick a category from Food, 
        Transport, Leisure, Education"))
    description = str(input("Please describe the expense in a few 
                  words"))
    c.execute("INSERT INTO Expenses (Amount,Category,Description,DateOfPurchase) VALUES (?,?,?,?)",
          (amount, category, description, Today))
    rerun = str(input("Would you like to add another item? (Yes/No)"))
    if (rerun == "Yes"):
        datain()
    else:
        connectdb.commit()
        c.close()
        connectdb.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to write a detailed solution, I think I'd need to see the schema for your database. However, I think the gist of what you're trying to achieve is something like:

```py
query = "SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM Expenses WHERE Month = ?;"
c.execute(query, theMonth)
result = c.fetchone()
```

And then `result` will be the Python variable you wanted to create.

Comment: Here is a screenshot of how the database looks. I don't think I can do it using Month as a variable since the DateOfPurchase field is in the format of YYYY-MM-DD
https://gyazo.com/b30ac6e8e1c9e0aa66da56edd7882fd2

Comment: There are two ways you could do this, then. The _best practice_ approach would be to re-design the database so that year, month, day, etc are in separate fields. (If this is a large project, you'll thank me later.)

Comment: A quicker, hackier way of doing it would be to change the `WHERE` clause of your `query` variable to `WHERE DateOfPurchase LIKE '2019-07%'`. But this sort of thing can get very ugly, very quickly. Don't say I didn't warn you!

Comment: P. S. If what I've suggested works, you'd really help me out by clicking the tick next to my answer.

Comment: It worked! However, if I print the executed query, it prints me the result value in list form e.g I was given the retrieved result in the form [(74.5,)]. Is there a way to convert this into float form instead of list so I can perform operations on it?

Comment: Ah, yes. I forgot about that mildly irritating feature of Python's SQLite package! `fetchone()` returns a _tuple_. Again, there are two ways around this, the quick way and the proper way. Quick: index the tuple, i.e. `extract = c.fetchone()` \\ `result = extract[0]`. Proper: get Python to return a _dictionary_ - generally a much more useful data structure. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3300464/how-can-i-get-dict-from-sqlite-query) provides a straightforward guide to doing this.

Comment: P. S. Thank you so much for accepting my answer. My first one!