# How to retrieve SQL result column value using column name in Python?

Tags: python, mysql

Is there a way to retrieve SQL result column value using column name instead of column index in Python? I'm using Python 3 with mySQL. The syntax I'm looking for is pretty much like the Java construct:

```
Object id = rs.get("CUSTOMER_ID");
```

I've a table with quite a number of columns and it is a real pain to constantly work out the index for each column I need to access. Furthermore the index is making my code hard to read.

Thanks!

Comment: You may want to provide more details like some code you are trying, python package you are using.

Comment: For more information about `cursor.description`, see [cursor.description](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#description)

Answer (score 99, accepted):

The [MySQLdb](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/) module has a [DictCursor](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb-1.2.2/public/MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor-class.html):

Use it like this (taken from [Writing MySQL Scripts with Python DB-API](http://www.kitebird.com/articles/pydbapi.html)):

```
cursor = conn.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
cursor.execute("SELECT name, category FROM animal")
result_set = cursor.fetchall()
for row in result_set:
    print "%s, %s" % (row["name"], row["category"])
```

**edit:** According to user1305650 this works for [`pymysql`](https://github.com/petehunt/PyMySQL) as well.

Comment: Tried this and it doesn't work too - got an error "TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not str"

Comment: Are you using the `MySQLdb` module?  Did you create your cursor exactly like this: `cursor = conn.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)`?

Comment: my bad! I didn't create the cursor as per your post. It works now - I just need to change MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor to pymysql.cursors.DictCursor because I use pymysql. Thanks!

Comment: Excellent.  You can accept this answer by pressing the checkmark to the the left.  If you really like it you can also add an upvote.  :)

Comment: I've accepted the answer, unfortunately I don't have the minimum reputation to upvote it :( Thanks again!

Comment: How to this with SQLite?

Comment: its actually alot simpler than this, you dont need any different modules: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56209874/1164342

Comment: Since you already know the two columns that are coming back, you could skip using the DictCursor and just do `name, category = row`. DictCursor makes since if you're selecting a lot of columns though.

Comment: @Hayden From the question "I've a table with quite a number of columns and it is a real pain to constantly work out the index for each column I need to access."

Comment: cursor.fetchall() worked with psycopg2. Thanks

Answer (score 35):

This post is old but may come up via searching.

Now you can use mysql.connector to retrive a dictionary as shown here:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursordict.html

Here is the example on the mysql site:

```
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(database='world')
cursor = cnx.cursor(dictionary=True)
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM country WHERE Continent = 'Europe'")

print("Countries in Europe:")
for row in cursor:
    print("* {Name}".format(Name=row['Name']))
```

Comment: This comment is missing two closing brackets at the end of the code sample, e.a. `print("* {Name}".format(Name=row['Name']`.

Comment: This is the best answer for >2020 and Python >3. This helped me a lot! No need for orderedDicts etc.

Comment: `cursor = cnx.cursor(dictionary=True)` dont you guys forget this ^_^

Answer (score 23):

you must look for something called " dictionary in cursor "

i'm using mysql connector and i have to add this parameter to my cursor , so i can use my columns names instead of index's

```py
db = mysql.connector.connect(
    host=db_info['mysql_host'],
    user=db_info['mysql_user'],
    passwd=db_info['mysql_password'],
    database=db_info['mysql_db'])

cur = db.cursor()

cur = db.cursor( buffered=True , dictionary=True)
```

Comment: This is the right answer.

Comment: Thanks, for a moment I thought I had to download another library, the real solution is yours

Answer (score 17):

import pymysql

```
# Open database connection
db = pymysql.connect("localhost","root","","gkdemo1")

# prepare a cursor object using cursor() method
cursor = db.cursor()

# execute SQL query using execute() method.
cursor.execute("SELECT * from user")

# Get the fields name (only once!)
field_name = [field[0] for field in cursor.description]

# Fetch a single row using fetchone() method.
values = cursor.fetchone()

# create the row dictionary to be able to call row['login']
**row = dict(zip(field_name, values))**

# print the dictionary
print(row)

# print specific field
print(**row['login']**)

# print all field
for key in row:
    print(**key," = ",row[key]**)

# close database connection
db.close()
```

Answer (score 7):

```
import mysql
import mysql.connector

db = mysql.connector.connect(
   host = "localhost",
    user = "root",
    passwd = "P@ssword1",
    database = "appbase"
)

cursor = db.cursor(dictionary=True)

sql = "select Id, Email from appuser limit 0,1"
cursor.execute(sql)
result = cursor.fetchone()

print(result)
# output =>  {'Id': 1, 'Email': 'me@gmail.com'}

print(result["Id"])
# output => 1

print(result["Email"])
# output => me@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 6):

python 2.7

```
import pymysql

conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', port=3306, user='root', passwd='password', db='sakila')

cur = conn.cursor()

n = cur.execute('select * from actor')
c = cur.fetchall()

for i in c:
    print i[1]
```

Comment: OP wants by attribute not index

Answer (score 3):

Of course there is. In Python 2.7.2+...

```
import MySQLdb as mdb
con =  mdb.connect('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'db');
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute('SELECT Foo, Bar FROM Table')
for i in range(int(cur.numrows)):
    foo, bar = cur.fetchone()
    print 'foo = %s' % foo
    print 'bar = %s' % bar
```

Comment: What do you think he's trying to do? Select the values by column name and assign them to variables seems pretty straight forward.

Comment: It looks like he wants a solution that's independent of column order.

Comment: this works too but it just proliferates my code with all the additional variables. I think the previous post by Steven Rumbalski is a better solution. Anyway thanks for your solution too.

Answer (score 2):

selecting values from particular column:

```
import pymysql
db = pymysql.connect("localhost","root","root","school")
cursor=db.cursor()
sql="""select Total from student"""
l=[]
try:
    #query execution
    cursor.execute(sql)
    #fetch all rows 
    rs = cursor.fetchall()
    #iterate through rows
    for i in rs:
        #converting set to list
        k=list(i)
        #taking the first element from the list and append it to the list
        l.append(k[0])
    db.commit()
except:
    db.rollback()
db.close()
print(l)
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide many details, but you could try something like this:

```
# conn is an ODBC connection to the DB
dbCursor = conn.cursor()
sql = ('select field1, field2 from table') 
dbCursor = conn.cursor()
dbCursor.execute(sql)
for row in dbCursor:
    # Now you should be able to access the fields as properties of "row"
    myVar1 = row.field1
    myVar2 = row.field2
conn.close()
```

Comment: sorry, it doesn't work. Though I'm unsure if it is because mySQL implementation or just DB-API-2.0 lack of support it.

Comment: Have you tried using pyodbc? It should be generic and support the same interface for every database.

Answer (score 1):

Dictionary Cursor might save your day

```
cursor = db.cursor(dictionary=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import mysql.connector as mysql
...
cursor = mysql.cnx.cursor()
cursor.execute('select max(id) max_id from ids')
(id) = [ id for id in cursor ]
```

Comment: Or even more concise the last line could be id = [ id for id in cursor ][0][0]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While this command may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this 
code answers the question improves its long-term value. [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

I use this method and by this I can access all the columns by there name.

```
import mysql.connector

mydb_local = mysql.connector.connect(
    host='localhost',
    user='root',
    password='password',
    database='db_test'
)
my_cursor = mydb_local.cursor(buffered=True)


def get_data(email):
    query = f"select * from user where email = '{email}';"
    my_cursor.execute(query)
    columns = [column[0] for column in my_cursor.description]
    user_id = my_cursor.fetchall()
    for row in user_id:
        user_data = dict(zip(columns, row))
    return user_data


def get():
    user_data = get_data('rabg')
    # Access the 'firstName' column
    print(f'{user_data["firstName"]},,,{user_data["lastName"]},,,{user_data["last_login_time"]}')


get()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This question was already satisfactorily anwered. In this case, please elaborate on how your answer adds to existing content.