# Connect mysql database in python

Tags: python, mysql

I have created a DB as follows:

```
+------------+-------+--------------+-------------------------------+
| Reg_exp    | Token | Integer_code | Attribute_value               |
+------------+-------+--------------+-------------------------------+
| WHITESPACE | -     |            0 | -                             |
| begin      | begin |            1 | -                             |
| end        | end   |            2 | -                             |
| if         | if    |            3 | -                             |
```

I could access the tuples of the database using the following command: (I have not included the connection part but only the query)

```
if input == str1:
    print "MATCH FOUND!!!"
    sql = "SELECT * FROM EXPRESSION WHERE Integer_code = 1"
    try:
        cursor.execute(sql)
        results = cursor.fetchall()
        for row in results:
            print (row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3])
    except:
        print "failed!!!"
```

The result I get is:

```
MATCH FOUND!!!
('begin', 'begin', 1L, '-')
```

I want to display the values in the form of a table along with the column names. How can I do that?

Comment: Sorry about earlier. I somehow misread your question. I think `cursor.description` will get the column names and maybe other column metadata as a tuple. http://www.mikusa.com/python-mysql-docs/docs/MySQLdb.cursors.html

Comment: Hmm, also looks like you can use `DictCursor`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10195139/how-to-retrieve-sql-result-column-value-using-column-name-in-python

Answer (score 0):

May be my answer is not useful for the OP who has not been online since he asked this question, but may be it will be useful for future members facing the same problem.

The OP is looking for a Python output in MySQL format:

```
mysql> SHOW COLUMNS FROM begueradj FROM begueradj;
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field           | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Reg_exp         | varchar(20) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| Token           | varchar(20) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| Integer_code    | int(2)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| Attribute_value | varchar(2)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

(my DB and table have the same name, by the way)

I created the same table as the OP's one and filled it with the same data.

It is good to see the world as a set of object, so my solution will be done in a class where we need to save the connexion parameters to MySQL server within a Python dictionary in the class consutructor `def __init__(self):`

```
self.config = { 'user':'begueradj',
                'passwd':'begueradj',
                'host':'127.0.0.1',
                'db':'begueradj',
               }
```

Of course, one needs to change these parameters to his ones.

Of course, trying to do a hack by yourself is not necessarily the best idea. For my solution, I opted for the use of  [`texttable`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/texttable/) which you can install by:

- First download the compressed module.
- Uncompress the file and change the directory to it.
- Finally, type this command: `sudo python setup.py install`

After executing the MySQL query (`self.sqlquery = """SELECT * FROM begueradj"""`), you will need the *[MySQLCursor.description Property](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-description.html)* to get the columns' names in a tuple format:

```
# Get columns' names
self.columns = [i[0] for i in self.cursor.description]
```

Note that is useful to transform the tuples to lists as `texttable` module works on lists.

## Python program:

I commented almost each line of my program solution below:

```
'''
Created on Mar 3, 2016

@author: begueradj
'''
import MySQLdb
import texttable

class Begueradj:
    """ Display MySQL table's content along with
    table's columns name as in pure MySQL format.
    """
    def __init__(self):
        """ Initialize MySQL server login parameters.
        Try to connect to communicate with MySQL database.
        """
        self.config = {'user':'begueradj',
                       'passwd':'begueradj',
                       'host':'127.0.0.1',
                       'db':'begueradj',
                       }
        # Try to log to MySQL server
        try:
            self.dbconnexion = MySQLdb.connect(**self.config)
        except MySQLdb.Error:
            print "Database connexion failure!"

        # Read the content of the MySQL table
        self.sqlquery = """SELECT * FROM beg"""

    def begueradj(self):
        """ Display MySQL table data.
        """
        self.cursor = self.dbconnexion.cursor()
        self.cursor.execute(self.sqlquery)

        # Get columns' names
        self.columns = [i[0] for i in self.cursor.description]

        self.tab = texttable.Texttable()
        self.tablerow = [[]]

       # Fetch all the rows from the query
        self.data = self.cursor.fetchall()

        # Must transform each tuple row to a list
        for r in self.data:
            self.tablerow.append(list(r))

        # Get the number of columns of the table
        self.tab.add_rows(self.tablerow)
        # Align displayed data within cells to left
        self.tab.set_cols_align(['l','l','l','l'])
        # Once again, convert each tuple  row to a list
        self.tab.header(list(self.columns))
        # Display the table (finally)
        print self.tab.draw()

        # Don't forget to close the connexion.
        self.dbconnexion.close()

# Main program
if __name__=="__main__":
    b=Begueradj()
    b.begueradj()
```

## Demo:

[image]