# PyMySQL and OrderedDict

Tags: python, python-2.7, pymysql

I've been using PyMySQL for a while now and created my own wrapper that I'm used to to shorthand writing queries.  Nonetheless I've been creating CSV files with OrderedDict because I need to keep the order the same but I realize that if I use PyMySQL for querying the database, I will not get the order the database is giving back.  This is a little annoying for spot checking CSV files if I wanted to just dump stuff rather than hand write the orders.

My question is, how do I use PyMySQL with OrderedDict? Currently my code is as follows:

```
import pymysql
conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user='root', passwd='', db='test')
cursor = conn.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
```

So whenever I query, I'll be getting a dictionary back:

```
cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM test""")
for row in cursor:
    pp(row)  # gives me dictionary
```

What I want is that when I roll through cursor I'm actually retrieving an OrderedDict of the columns in the order they come in from the database.

Something like:

```
cursor = conn.cursor(pymysql.cursors.OrderedDict)
```

Comment: add another column which holds, source row and order by that when querying?

Comment: @Busturdust - I could write in my wrapper a function say "query_ordered" or something that has the select fields in a list and then can create a generator for yielding ordereddict in replace of the dictionary but it if I can just get at a solution without writing that and that would also play well with my wrapper already, I would rather have that.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could use `cursors.DictCursorMixin` and change its `dict_type` to [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) (the default is [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict)):

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from pymysql.cursors import DictCursorMixin, Cursor

class OrderedDictCursor(DictCursorMixin, Cursor):
    dict_type = OrderedDict
```

Then you can use the new cursor class as shown below

```
cursor = conn.cursor(OrderedDictCursor)
```

Comment: Works exactly as expected.  Just saw that in PyMySQL's github repository as well.  Speedy answer!  Thanks!