# Ordering the columns of MySql table using Python

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I'm beginner in SQL.

Consider my simple code:

```
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='',
                              host='127.0.0.1', database='employees')
cursor = cnx.cursor()

cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM people ORDER BY Height DESC, Weight')

my_result = cursor.fetchall()

cnx.close()

for x in my_result:
  print(x[0], x[1], x[2])
```

I have a **people** table in my **employees** database with columns **name**, **Height** and **Weight**. If I run this code, it prints the desired sorting and there's no problem. But, it seems that this code essentially doesn't change the order of rows of the table. I mean, now if I run

```
SELECT * FROM people;
```

in terminal I get the latter table (which does not have the desired order). Now, my question is:

**How can I change the order of the table *to obtain a new table with desired sorting using Python*? Is it possible**?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SELECT results with wrong column order with PyMySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32503795/select-results-with-wrong-column-order-with-pymysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new table like the old one and insert rows with the desired order, otherwise always run your query with ORDER BY.

To create a new table you can run a query similar to:

```
CREATE TABLE people_sorted LIKE people; 
INSERT people_sorted SELECT * FROM people ORDER BY Height DESC, Weight;
```