# Amazon Connect with RDS SQL thorugh Lambda issue

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

I want to be able to tell a customer what their claim status is( by matching the number they call with to a number in the database with a corresponding claimprogress. So far I am able to return the callers number via the CustomerEndpoint address but can't seem to figure out how to take that CustomerEndpoint information and use it with RDS. I assume from my little python knowledge that an IF statement may work but have had no luck so far.
[image]

Comment: What do you mean "can't use it with RDS" can you connect to RDS from the lambda?

Comment: yeah sorry, when I test it I can retrieve the information from rds. However I can't seem to figure out how the information from the database can then be compared to the CustomerEndpoint number (which I can also retrive individually) in order to get the claim status

Comment: Shouldn't you add a `WHERE phone_number = "customer number"` to your DB query instead of iterating through all the rows?

Comment: Take a look at this answer on how to get the value from database object https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10195139/how-to-retrieve-sql-result-column-value-using-column-name-in-python

Comment: I'm sorry, I dont understand? Can the CustomerEndPointAddress(customer number) is gathered through connect, am I able to reference that even if it is not a column name with the database

Comment: Is CustomerEndPointAddress(customer number), it's not in your code?

Comment: Sorry my bad the ['CustomerEndpoint']['Address'] that I have is correct.

Comment: The value of `events["Details"]["ContactData"]...["Address"]` is a phone number right?  And you want to get the claim number of a customer with that number right?