# in MySQL and python how to access fields by using field name not field index

Tags: python, mysql

python & mysql
I am making a query on MySQL database in python module,  as follows :

```
qry = "select qtext,a1,a2,a3,a4,rightanswer from question where qno = 1 ")

mycursor.execute(qry)
myresult = mycursor.fetchone()
qtext.insert('1', myresult[0])
```

I access the fields by their index number (i.e myresult[0])
my question is how can I access fields by their field-name instead of their index in the query ?

Comment: Here's the answer you need
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10195139/how-to-retrieve-sql-result-column-value-using-column-name-in-python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to retrieve SQL result column value using column name in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10195139/how-to-retrieve-sql-result-column-value-using-column-name-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

I have to add the following line before executing the query

mycursor = mydb.cursor(dictionary=True)

this line converts the query result to a dictionary that enabled me  to access fields by their names names instead of index as follows

```
qtext.insert('1', myresult["qtext"])
qanswer1.insert('1',myresult["a1"]) # working
qanswer2.insert('1',myresult["a2"]) # working   
qanswer3.insert('1',myresult["a3"]) # working   
qanswer4.insert('1',myresult["a4"]) # working
r = int(myresult["rightanswer"])
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is your answer: [How to retrieve SQL result column value using column name in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10195139/how-to-retrieve-sql-result-column-value-using-column-name-in-python)

````
cursor.execute("SELECT name, category FROM animal")
result_set = cursor.fetchall()
for row in result_set:
    print "%s, %s" % (row["name"], row["category"])```
````