# python get elements in array by column name like in php

Tags: php, python, arrays

I want to be able to do something like the code below (which is PHP):

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $name = $row['name'];
    $event = $row['event'];
```

in python. So getting an element by its index. What is the best way?

Comment: Use Python Dictionary, Python Lists can only access by their index.

Comment: do you talk about SQL results array specifically, or general arrays ?

Comment: Use something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/811548/sqlite-and-python-return-a-dictionary-using-fetchone

Comment: @georgesl i'm talking about SQL results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, using [dictionaries](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict), which are built in types.

```
d = {'name': 'user'}
print d['name']
user
```

Comment: This seems useful. Can you show me how to get my 'name' variable for every row in practice?

Answer (score 1):

You use the DictCursor object from the MySQLdb package. This will produce a dictionary (mapping) in the result set rather than the usual tuples.

```
import MySQLdb                                                                                                                      
from MySQLdb import cursors

def fetchallmap(self, q, *args):                                                                                                
    """Fetch all rows into a dictionary.                                                                                        
    """                                                                                                                         
    curs = self._connection.cursor(cursors.DictCursor)                                                                                   
    curs.execute(q, args)                                                                                                       
    res = curs.fetchall()                                                                                                       
    curs.close()                                                                                                                
    self._connection.commit()                                                                                                            
    return res
```

This will return a list of dictionaries (mappings). If you just want one row, just substitute `fetchoone` instead of `fetchall`.

```
def fetchonemap(self, q, *args):                                                                                                
    """Fetch one row into a dictionary.                                                                                         
    """                                                                                                                         
    curs = self._connection.cursor(cursors.DictCursor)                                                                                   
    curs.execute(q, args)                                                                                                       
    res = curs.fetchone()                                                                                                       
    curs.close()                                                                                                                
    self._connection.commit()                                                                                                            
    return res
```

Comment: could you show me how this would work in practice for my case please? How would i get 'name' and other variables for each row given?

Comment: here is an example : [http://www.kitebird.com/articles/pydbapi.html#TOC_10](http://www.kitebird.com/articles/pydbapi.html#TOC_10)

Comment: post as 'answer' so i can accept it :)) that worked! thanks alot